# Linux: CPU and memory usage for a program

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that calls different c++ programs (some of them are multithread). I want to know what is the CPU and memory usage (maximum or average) during the execution of that script. There is a special tool for that?

Thanks.

Comment: `top` is ok but I think that `htop` is better. You can install `htop` by command `sudo apt-get install htop` in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to dig into  `/proc/<pid>/...` (where `<pid>` is the process ID of the programs that you've launched) you can use `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the "program"'s process name:

`ps -C "processName" -o %cpu,%mem`